# Nginx proxy cache invalidating request to s3

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, proxy

I have set up a proxy from my application server to a private s3 bucket to cache requests. I was having some trouble with it where s3 was rejecting my download requests (403 forbidden) and after some experimentation it seems that disabling cacheing allows the valid request to go through. But the entire purpose of the proxy is as a cache. I guess the proxy is altering the request in some way but I don't understand how. Does anyone have any insight into how enabling caching in nginx alters requests and if there is some way to over come this?

Here is the relevent config.

```
http {

    proxy_cache_path          /home/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=S3_CACHE:10m inactive=24h max_size=500m;
    proxy_temp_path           /home/cache/tmp;

    server {

        server_name my-cache-server.com;
        listen 80;

        proxy_cache S3_CACHE;

        location / {

            proxy_buffering        on;
            proxy_pass             http://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/;
            proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        }
    }
}
```

if I remove the line `proxy_cache S3_CACHE;`

Here is the difference between the nginx access logs with proxy_cache disabled vs. enabled... In the first case the headers are passed, accepted, and then a get request is made that returns the images. In the second case (with cache enabled) the headers are sent and then rejected, resulting in a 403 error which stops the performance.vidigami.com test server running

WORKING...

```
MY_IP - - [09/Nov/2014:23:19:04 +0000] "HEAD https://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/Test%20image.jpg      
HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "aws-sdk-nodejs/2.0.23 darwin/v0.10.32"

MY_IP - - [09/Nov/2014:23:19:04 +0000] "GET https://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/Test%20image.jpg 
HTTP/1.1" 200 69475 "-" "aws-sdk-nodejs/2.0.23 darwin/v0.10.32"
```

NOT WORKING...

```
MY_IP - - [09/Nov/2014:23:20:08 +0000] "HEAD https://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/Test%20image.jpg 
HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "aws-sdk-nodejs/2.0.23 darwin/v0.10.32"
```

Answer (score 3):

If AWS S3 rejects requests (HTTP 403), the origin call is invalid, this is not caching or Nginx problem. In your case Nginx itself accesses S3 via http (80 port), make sure your S3 URL created to be accessed with no HTTPS. Othewise, make *proxy_pass https://...*

This directive **proxy_pass_request_headers** is not required, also **proxy buffering** is on by default. It's highly recommended to enable access/error logs.

To use HTTP 1.1 keep alive with backend and perform caching use the following directives:

```
location / {
  proxy_http_version     1.1;
  proxy_set_header       Connection "";
  proxy_set_header       Host 'MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com';
  proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
  proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;

  proxy_cache            S3_CACHE;
  proxy_cache_valid      200 24h;
  proxy_cache_valid      403 15m;
  proxy_cache_bypass     $http_cache_purge;
  add_header             X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

  proxy_pass             http://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/;

  access_log             s3.access.log;
  error_log              s3.error.log;
}
```

Cache invalidation works via HTTP header **Cache-Purge**, so header **X-Cached** displays MISS/HIT depending on full request or retrieve from cache respectively. To perform cache invalidation just do:

```
curl -I 'http://your_server.com/file' -H 'Cache-Purge: 1'
```

It's important to choose appropriate S3 endpoint to avoid DNS redirect:

```
us-east-1       s3.amazonaws.com
us-west-2       s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
us-west-1       s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
eu-west-1       s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com  
eu-central-1    s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
ap-southeast-1  s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
ap-southeast-2  s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
ap-northeast-1  s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
sa-east-1       s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly what's happening. When I add the proxy_cache line, the request is invalid, but when I take it away, it is not. So, I don't believe it is an issue with the original request. Also, I have seem the snippet you have posted, but as I mentioned, I am using a private bucket and so the headers must stay intact as the sdk is sending Authorization, which when removed, invalidates the request. Also... without `proxy_pass_headers` the request is also invalidated and is the only line that has worked to actually allow the request through the proxy in any way.

Comment: I posted configuration that works in production more than a year, so I do believe this config works correctly. The only thing I didn't notice, private file URLs have arguments: http ://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/$uri$is_args$args; Arguments omit due to proxying by default.

Comment: Is there someway I can log the exact URL of the incoming request on the proxy? Because I'm pretty sure it is simply the file name with no arguments and the actual authentication information for access to the private bucket is being sent in headers, for instance `Authorization '';` in your code needs to be receeived by S3 as `Authorization 'ACCESS_KEY:SIGNATURE' which is constructed by the sdk. How can it possibly authenticate if you are destroying the authorization header?

Comment: AFAIK actual authentication information is  mix of signature and time stamp as arguments most of time. Let's try to enable access log and error log to see what happens inside.

Comment: It comes from the SDK as a header in this form...
Authorization 'AWS access_key:calculated_signature'
I can read it in nginx by logging $http_authorization
There is a different signature for each request based on expiry date, the content of the file, my secret key, and the current date. I don't know if this is what is being altered. It could be anything really. I'm going to try to log all the headers that come in the initial request, and then all the headers that are sent by nginx to S3 and see the difference. I'm just not sure how to do that yet. I added some info to the question.

Comment: So it goes like this (chronologically)...with cache disabled: Client makes HEAD request --> proxy --> S3 THEN Client makes GET request --> proxy --> S3 THEN S3 sends image --> proxy --> client. with cache enabled: Client makes HEAD request --> proxy transforms this into a GET --> S3 THEN proxy sends 403 --> client AND THEN S3 sends 403 --> proxy. WTF? So the rejection that the client receives isn't even coming from S3 it is coming directly from the proxy, and then S3 rejects the proxy.

Comment: **proxy_cache_key** is equal $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri, but it most likely %20 (space representation) breaks things, try different proxy_cache_key or file name with no spaces.

Comment: @mikhailov, in your implementation `-H 'Cache-Purge: 1'` isn't really a cache invalidation, but just a one-time bypassing.

Comment: @korya in fact no, it definitely invalidates a certain cache key